# error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at Function (<anonymous>) at assertExpression

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm trying to use jade on building my views when I try to make a link on an image I get [this stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyTpH.png). How do I to fix this, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the width and height attribute values need be quoted or you need to drop the 'px' suffix at the end of the numbers. Attribute values need to be valid javascript expressions.